# I extract a file apk To update the old version java to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have an old app (Android Studio java) on the google play store now
I finished designing it Flutter and use package name
now How do I extract a file apk To update the old version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate an application bundle from your Flutter project, you need to do the following:

- Open the terminal and cd into the directory of your project
- Run `flutter build appbundle`
- The release bundle for your app will be created at `your_project_name/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`.

If you prefer to build an APK, there are others steps you need to follow.

You can see them [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android).